# error 404 redirect not working with my .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried using

> ErrorDocument 404 /abc/404.php

But when the wrong URL is entered it redirects to the main page, not to the 404 error page

I have a htaccess file with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search(?:\.php)?\?search=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/page/(.*)/?$ search.php?search=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?search=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/page/(.*)/?$ category.php?id=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /abc/404.php
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your htaccess file in your question, could you please do let us know which URL is NOT rewriting? for better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: all rewrite rules working fine sir, but when I enter wrong url with base URL (domain.com/wrongurl) it redirects to the main page, not to the 404 error page

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 pretty sure that would be anything that doesn't match `^(search|category).*`

Comment: Why have you got multiple `if` blocks with multiple `RewriteEngine On` statements?

Comment: @Steven, Hello Steven, No, I think that will look for either search or category strings are coming in start of URI. I think problem could be errordocument's place, it should be up I believe.

Comment: Your last block of RewriteConditions and -Rule will redirect _all_ requests that do not match a physically existing file or folder, to the index.php. So there _are_ no requests any more, that could cause an _actual_ 404. In a case like this, checking whether the requested URL matches any existing content, and responding with the 404 error page you want when not, also has to be handled by your index.php now.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I think you read that wrong: I wasn't suggesting using that regex. Rather I'm pointing out that when you asked for a URL that doesn't work, I'm saying that anything that doesn't match that pattern (and isn't a real file/directory) _won't work for the OP_. It has nothing to do with the placement of `ErrorDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

These two rules...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Replace any URL that is accessed with the replacement... Unless the accessed URL is a real file/directory. As per the `RewriteCond` rules preceding them:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

If you don't want to divert every request that isn't a real file/directory then you need to change those rules...

Comment: sir can you suggest me how to change the rules

Comment: @Bunny, as per your shown samples solutions will be given. Its better to mention all urls samples from which url to which url in backend you want to rewrite fir better understanding of your question, kindly do edit your question, thank you.

Comment: @Bunny Well that all depends on what you intended the `^(.*)$` rules to do?

Comment: Yes sir, when I remove all rewrite rules it perfectly redirecting to 404 page

Comment: "localhost/abc/postname" (original url)... "localhost/abc/postnanefff" (wrong url) it redirects to "localhost/abc/", not to the 404 error page --and-- "localhost/abc/category/catname" (original url)... "localhost/abc/category/catnamefff" (wrong url) it redirects to "localhost/abc/category", not to the 404 error page. sry im not perfect in english. Thank You

Comment: It would help if you could add all possible URL formats to the question. Currently it seems like you could just as easily replace your last rule with a redirect to 404 or do away with the rule?